# Can WSL 2 be opened without relying on the DNS Client service?

Tags: dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hosts

I recently added a large number of entries to my hosts file on Windows 11 (200,000+). The DNS Client (Dnscache) service struggled predictably with this, so I disabled it via the registry.

WSL 2 will not start after doing so and gives me the below error:

```
The service has not been started.
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVm/ConfigureNetworking/0x80070426

[process exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)]
You can now close this terminal with Ctrl+D, or press Enter to restart.
```

I tested re-enabling the DNS Client service, and doing so allows WSL to open.

I tried modifying /etc/wsl.conf to see if stopping the auto-generation of /etc/resolv.conf would help, but the issue remains. This is apparently not the only part of WSL that relies on DNS Client.

Is there any way to remove WSL's dependency on the DNS Client service?

Comment: I think you should find a solution that doesn't require 200,000+ entries in the hosts file and allows running the DNS Client service.

Comment: Good thought to disable the `/etc/resolv.conf` auto-generation.  You followed the [8 second rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#the-8-second-rule), I assume, right?  If so, it's probably something that is hardcoded into the WSL2 init process.  Worth asking (probably as a feature request or discussion) on [the WSL Github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL) if you don't get any ideas here.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I did, and I tested with a clean boot in there as well. And I'll take a look at their repo, thank you!